# Using sed to delete item in a list

Tags: bash

I am trying to use sed to delete a particular item in a list in a text file that is formatted in a particular way. I'll simply illustrate by example; I have ...

```
ITEMS="$ITEM $ITEM1 $ITEM2 $ITEM3"
```

And I want to delete $ITEM from the list so this will become ...

```
ITEMS="$ITEM1 $ITEM2 $ITEM3"
```

The list could also even just contain $ITEM alone without the numbered $ITEM's, like ...

```
ITEMS="$ITEM"
```

And this would become

```
ITEMS=""
```

Once $ITEM is deleted out of it of course.

It is not known how many $ITEM's exist in the list while executing this find/delete. The said text file contains other text besides this line, but ITEMS= is unique to the beginning of the lines of the text file, i.e. this is the only line that starts with ITEMS=.  So basically, I would like to find the line beginning with ITEMS= and delete the $ITEM element out of it.  How could this best be accomplished using sed?

Comment: By `$ITEM` do you literally mean a dollar-sign followed by the word `ITEM`? Or is it a Bash variable? Or do you have a fixed string, and `$ITEM` is just your informal notation for it for purposes of this question?

Comment: `$ITEM` is literally a dollar-sign followed by a word. It is not a variable in this case. The regex characters including `$` and `"` need to be accounted for accordingly with a preceding \.

Comment: then you have to single-quote it, otherwise it won't work: compare `ITEMS="$ITEM"; echo "$ITEMS"` to `ITEMS='$ITEM'; echo "$ITEMS"`

Comment: There is no need for single quoting.  You can always use a backslash before the dollar sign to remove regex ability.

Comment: So sorry to have bothered you.

Comment: @JoSo You didn't bother me. You were offering your help and that's always appreciated. I was just making a statement.

Comment: Your statement is misleading. The working notation using only backslashes is `ITEMS=\$ITEM\ \$ITEM\ \$ITEM`. Also, this has nothing to do with regexes.

Comment: Also see [“egrep: empty (sub)expression” when attempting to filter out words from a list](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/238888/56041). Its a Grep and Sed question, and the accepted answer is the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the spaces before and after `$ITEM` are really annoying. :)

try this line:

```
sed -r 's/"\$ITEM /"/; s/\$ITEM //g; s/ ?\$ITEM"/"/' file
```

test with some example:

```
kent$ echo 'ITEMS="$ITEM"'|sed -r 's/"\$ITEM /"/; s/\$ITEM //g; s/ ?\$ITEM"/"/'                                                                                  
ITEMS=""
7pLaptop 20:57:44 /home/kent/myCodes/vim/last256
kent$echo 'ITEMS="$ITEM $ITEM1 $ITEM2 $ITEM $ITEM3 $ITEM"'|sed -r 's/"\$ITEM /"/; s/\$ITEM //g; s/ ?\$ITEM"/"/'
ITEMS="$ITEM1 $ITEM2 $ITEM3"
```

**EDIT**

for OP's comment, add explanation.

```
's/"\$ITEM /"/;     #step1 check if the first element is $ITEM, do sub
s/\$ITEM //g;       #step2 handle the middle elements
s/ ?\$ITEM"/"/'     #step3 handle the last element case. also this handles single ("$ITEM") case.
```

I used 3 steps because OP wants to have same format (single space separated values) after the processing. There maybe simpler/nicer solution for it, I just thought of this way, do the substitution/formating in 3 steps. :(

Comment: Yes it did work for me!  Thank you very much.  Please see my follow-up requests above.  I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If it's a huge file you might get a small performance boost with something like `sed -r '/ITEMS=/!b;s/...'`, that way you skip the replacement attempts on lines that don't matter. (`'/ITEMS=/{s/...;}'` also works but the branch to the end, b, is simpler)

Comment: @Kent could you please explain how your command works in layman's terms?

Comment: @Kent Also, is there a way to do this only on the line beginning with ITEMS= ?  I noticed your command does a sort of replace-all, regardless of line's beginning content.

Comment: @user2150250 yes, if the line beginning is `$ITEM`and one space, it would be replaced as well.The line in your example is not beginning with `$`

Comment: I simply added the item to match on before the first slash, and accounted for any leading spaces.  So now I have `sed "/^\s*ITEMS=/s/\"\$ITEM /\"/; /^\s*ITEMS=/s/\$ITEM //g; /^\s*ITEMS=/s/ ?\$ITEM\"/\"/"`.  Seems to work great.

Comment: @Kent Also, I was wondering why it is necessary to use the extended regular expressions?

Comment: @user2150250 you can remove `-r`. since at the beginning I wrote some groups in that sed line, with `(..)`, I don't like escaping them all the time, so I added -r. but final version, I removed those `()`, the -r is not necessary.

Comment: @Kent The third/last part of the command (the one that replaces the last element or single $ITEM case) doesn't work with framing the sed in double quotes as I have done a few comments above.  Is this a problem with the question mark within the double quotes or do I have it written incorrectly above?

Comment: @user2150250 question mark is for the `="$ITME"` case. put some more examples in your question (EDIT the question, you have more code format support too), so that we could know which one doesn't work and why.  for the two examples in your question, the sed line works.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on what is a "word" for you, this probably will do what you want:

```
echo 'a list of words' | sed 's/\<list\>//g'
```

Comment: this just removed the word "list", but leaves the two spaces there, right?

Comment: yes. Depending on what your semantics are, you must change this to your needs. Chances are that `s/\syourword\>\|\<yourword\s//g` might be your fit (`\|` means "alternative" and `\s` means "whitespace: tab or space" here)